# mysql - How to make sure mysql database is successfully connected in Flask using flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm trying to build a backend using Flask. I know how to connect `sqlite` in Flask. But it seems that connecting `mysql` is more complicated. 
I tried

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost/test'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

admin = User('admin', 'admin@example.com')

db.create_all() # In case user table doesn't exists already. Else remove it.

db.session.add(admin)

db.session.commit() # This is needed to write the changes to database

User.query.all()

User.query.filter_by(username='admin').first()
```

The program could be executed without error. However, I use `Navicat` to check if the table is added to the database, I found the `test` database is still empty.

Actually I don't quite understand **what exactly is a database connection**. Because it seems that I can create a connection in `Navicat`, and I also connect the database in the code, what are the differences between these connections?

I wonder whether there is something wrong with the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` because I found that there are several users

[image]

With these questions, I couldn't make sure whether I connected to the database successfully. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your database doesn't have autocommit set to on.
You can 'force' it from your application

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={'autocommit': True})
```

Comment: hey mate, I am having the same problem, can you have a look please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323929/mysql-table-not-created-using-flask-and-pymysql