# MySQL Table not created using Flask and PyMySQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This maybe a duplicate, but all the solutions to the other questions did not help me.

I am trying to modularize my code where I am moving my config files to a separate file called settings.py.

To run the code i am going running from my terminal "python3 manage.py shell"
Python not updating 
then I execute

```
from flask_blog import db
from author.models import Author
db.create_all()
```

---

> Hence the QUESTION is: Why is the database not being updated?

---

The three file I have that concern config are:

**manage.py** *Handles the server set-up (in simple wordds)*

**settings.py** *Handles the database for now*

**models.py** *The database model*

**__init__.py** *The **init*** file

The code is below is the **settings.py**

```
import os

SECRET_KEY = 'NOTHING FOR NOW'
DEBUG = True
DB_USERNAME = 'root'
DB_PASSWORD = '1234'
BLOG_DB_NAME = 'blog2'
DB_HOST = os.getenv('IP', '127.0.0.1')
DB_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://root@127.0.0.1:blog'
# DB_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://%s:%s@%s/%s' % (DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, BLOG_DB_NAME)

SQLALCHEMY_DB_URI = DB_URI
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
```

The other file called **manage.py** (below) which handles the basic project config to run.

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

from flask.ext.script import Manager, Server
from flask_blog import app

manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command("runserver", Server(
            use_debugger = True,
            use_reloader = True,
            host = os.getenv('IP', '127.0.0.1'),
            port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))
        ))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

And lastly the database model below. **models.py**

```
from flask_blog import db

class Author(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(35), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    is_author = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    def __init__(self, fullname, email, username, password, is_author=False):
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.is_author = is_author

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Author %r>' % self.username
```

The **__init__.py** is below

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('settings')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from blog import views
from author import views
```

If you want to see the entire project then [click here](https://github.com/Developing-Story-s/flask_blog.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `settings.py`, try replacing

```
SQLALCHEMY_DB_URI = DB_URI
```

with

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = DB_URI
```

And `DB_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://root@127.0.0.1:blog'`

with

```
DB_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://root@127.0.0.1/blog'
```

according to connection URI format:

```
dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the your response. 
`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = DB_URI` did  the trick